# Check if String one contains String two in java

Tags: java, string, indexof

> Task:   Write a method that receives 2 string parameters and checks if the second string is contained by the first one. The method will return a 
>   boolean. Example: returns true for “The Witcher” and “Witcher”.

```
import java.util.*;

class Dcoder {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        System.out.println(method("The Witcher","Witcher"));
    }

    public static boolean method(String str1, String str2) {
        String s1 = "The Witcher";
        boolean s2 = s1.indexOf("Witcher") != -1 ? true : false;
        return s2;
    }
}
```

My questions: how do I write code so that I only specify "The Witcher" and "Witcher" in main method.

Comment: Hint: your method isn't using your parameters (`str1` and `str2`) at all... start thinking what those parameters are meant to receive, and how you might want to use them.

Comment: You can replace the last line with `return s2 == true ? true : false;`. You shouldn't, but you can.

Comment: Your entire method should be `return str1.contains(str2);`

Comment: I put return str1.contains(str2); now it works even if I put other strings in main method to compare. That's very helpful. Thanks. But can I solve method without mentioning "The Witcher" and "Witcher"?

Answer (score 0):

The strings used to make the comparisons in your method aren't actually the strings you passed in into the function as arguments. Also, there's already a method in Java that lets you do this easily, which goes as follows:

```
String s1 = "The Witcher";
Boolean result = s1.contains("Witcher");
```

Comment: Thanks for the method Boolean result = s1.contains("Witcher"); I used it instead boolean s2 = s1.indexOf("Witcher") != -1 ? true : false; and it works. Didn't quite understand about " aren't actually the strings" I wonder if there is a way not to mention "The Witcher" and "Witcher" in method  and still be able to compare them in main method?